# Expand a metric around a point

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, calculus, approximations

Say that I have a metric for a plane $ds^{2}=d\tau^{2} + dy^{2}$. Now, let $\tau = r \cos\theta$ and $y=r \sin\theta$.

Consider the metric
$$ds^{2}=dr^{2} + r^{2}\,d \theta^2.$$
Say that I am looking at a point $r_{2}$. How would I consider variations around that point? I am not sure how to expand this metric around a certain point in the $r$ direction. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The metric components are $g_{rr}=1,g_{r\theta}=g_{\theta r}=0, g_{\theta\theta}=r^2$, so the only one which changes with position is $g_{\theta\theta}$. It shouldn't be difficult to approximate that in a neighborhood of some point $(r_0,\theta_0)$.

Answer (score 3):

That is a flat metric ($R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=0$), so it looks the same expanded around any point with exactly the same form.  Define new coordinates as $x_{1}=\tau-(r_{2})_{\tau}$ and $y_{1}=y-(r_{2})_{y}$ [where $(r_{2})_{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$-component of the position vector $r_{2}$].  In these coordinates, the metric is
$$ ds^{2}=dx_{1}^{2}+dx_{2}^{2}. $$
Or you can define polar coordinates around this point:  $R=\sqrt{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}$ and $\tan\vartheta=-y_{1}/x_{1}$, in which case the metric is
$$ ds^{2}=dR^{2}+R^{2}\,d\vartheta^{2}.$$